# OS X / iOS & TCP: Why CFSocketSendData crashes application if called after connection is reset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-foundation

I using client code similar to this:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CFSocket.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void receiveData(CFSocketRef s, 
                         CFSocketCallBackType type, 
                         CFDataRef address, 
                         const void *data, 
                         void *info)
{
    CFDataRef df = (CFDataRef) data;
    int len = CFDataGetLength(df);
    if(len <= 0) return;

    CFRange range = CFRangeMake(0,len);
    UInt8 buffer[len];
    NSLog(@"Received %d bytes from socket %d\n", 
                  len, CFSocketGetNative(s));
    CFDataGetBytes(df, range, buffer);
    NSLog(@"Client received: %s\n", buffer); 
    NSLog(@"As UInt8 coding: %@", df);
}

int main ()
{
    CFSocketRef s = CFSocketCreate(NULL, PF_INET, 
                                            SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 
                                            kCFSocketDataCallBack, 
                                            receiveData, 
                                            NULL);
    struct sockaddr_in      sin; 
    struct hostent           *host;

    host = gethostbyname("********");      
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    memcpy(&(sin.sin_addr), host->h_addr,host->h_length); 
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(888);

    CFDataRef address, data;
    UInt8 message[] = "Hello world";
    CFRunLoopSourceRef source;

    address = CFDataCreate(NULL, (UInt8 *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    data = CFDataCreate(NULL, message, sizeof(message));

    CFSocketConnectToAddress(s, address, 0);
    CFSocketSendData(s, NULL, data, 0);

    CFRelease(address);
    CFRelease(data);

    source = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, s, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), 
                       source, 
                       kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    CFRelease(source);
    CFRelease(s);
    CFRunLoopRun(); 
}
```

It sends data and got response properly. But TCP should not just send data, it should send data RELIABLY.

I tested such chronology:

1. Client calls `CFSocketConnectToAddress`
2. Server authorizes client
3. But now server app process crashes, and server -> client sends RST flag.
4. And after it, client calls `CFSocketSendData`.

I expected what `CFSocketSendData` returns error or at least throw an exception, but it causes crash of application, and @try-catch takes no effect.

Comment: What is the crash?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use explicit address in 2nd param? See if u are getting an error after that.

CFSocketSendData(s, , data, 0);

Comment: I tried it now, but nothing changed. Because where is no correlation between this argument and crashing *with server-ReSeTed socket*. Do not answer if do not know answer.